# actually i create account application i went display opening amt

Tags: c#-4.0, variables

> Blockquote

wpf application 
actually i create account application i went display opening amt.  opening amt equal to dr_amt-cr_amt . dr_amt and cr_amt is colume name of amt table there for i can do

```
enter code here
```

double a, b, c;
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("my conn");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select sum(dr_amt),sum(cr_amt) from amt where id='"+tex1.Text+"'", con);

```
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())

        {
            a = Convert.ToDouble(dr[0]);
            b = Convert.ToDouble(dr[1]);
        }
        c = a - b;

        textBox3.Text =Convert.ToString( c);
```

> Blockquote

at bulid this code i see error Use of unassigned local variable'a' and 'b' how can i do

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of unassigned local variable at run time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454800/use-of-unassigned-local-variable-at-run-time)

Answer (score 0):

Because a and b will not be assigned if dr.Read() is empty.

```
double a = 0;
double b = 0;
```

And if the reader return more than one row c will be bases on the last row only.