# Use of unassigned local variable at run time

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2005

wpf application actually I create account application I went display opening amt. opening amt equal to dr_amt-cr_amt . dr_amt and cr_amt is column name of amt table there for i can do

```
double a, b, c;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("my conn");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select sum(dr_amt),sum(cr_amt) from amt where id='"+tex1.Text+"'", con);


con.Open();

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())

{
    a = Convert.ToDouble(dr[0]);
    b = Convert.ToDouble(dr[1]);
}
c = a - b;

textBox3.Text =Convert.ToString( c);
```

at bulid this code i see error Use of unassigned local variable'a' and 'b' how can i do

Answer (score 2):

> at bulid this code i see error Use of unassigned local variable'a' and 'b'

Yes, you would do. They're not definitely assigned, because your `while` loop may not execute.

What would you expect the result to be if there are no rows? The answer to that question will determine what you should do. (Also, if there's *more* than one row, only the last row will contribute to the result - is that deliberate?)

For example, you *could* just give them values to start with:

```
double a = 0, b = 0, c;
```

That will give you a result of 0 if there are no rows. If that's what you want...

(I'd declare the variables as late as you can, mind you.)

Additionally, **please** use parameterized SQL. Your current code is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Oh, and use `using` statements to make sure you close your command and exception appropriately.

Comment: Jon's suggestion (related to SQL Injection vulnerability of your code) is explained by [Jeff Atwood on his blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). Please follow his advise!

Comment: @user1464596: Well I've given you *one* piece of code... but really you should read the advice carefully, and then try to follow it yourself. If I just spoon-feed you code, you're less likely to learn for next time.

Comment: There can't be more than one row; the output is an aggregate (two `SUM`s) for a given `id` with no grouping.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Right, we can know that from the SQL - but I'd quite possibly assert that in the code as well. (Whenever you have a `while` loop, it's worth considering the options of how many times it will execute.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a and b because maybe the while loop won't execute even one iteration when there is no data in dr.

```
double a = 0, b = 0, c;
```